# Unknown type in structure

Tags: c, structure

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    STATUSTRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransitions;
} STATE;

typedef struct
{
    char c;
    STATE final;
} STATUSTRANSITION;
```

STATE doesn't know STATUSTRANSITION. How can I fix this problem? When I put STATUSTRANSITION above STATE, then I have the same problem with STATUSTRANSITION since it has STATE.

EDIT: Just to be clear. I get the 'Unknown type' exception for the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a type in a declaration, you need to either *define* or *declare* it ahead of the use. The only exception is the name of the `struct` itself being defined: you can use its tag to declare fields inside the structure itself.

In your case you should provide a forward declaration of `STATUSTRANSITION`, like this:

```
struct STATUSTRANSITION;

typedef struct 
{
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    struct STATUSTRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransitions;
} STATE;

typedef struct STATUSTRANSITION
{
    char c;
    STATE final;
} STATUSTRANSITION;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/7k4UIY)

Comment: The first line of your example is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
typedef struct statustransition STATUSTRANSITION;

typedef struct
{
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    STATUSTRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransitions;
} STATE;

struct statustransition
{
    char c;
    STATE final;
};
```

Comment: Why does it has to be is low case?

Comment: @DennisvonEich Tag name can be anything. Let's change you want.